# How to change props to state in React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In Simple react class component we used to change the props to state this way:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      pitch: props.booking.pitch,
      email: props.booking.email,
      firstName: props.booking.firstName,
      arrivalDate: props.booking.arrivalDate
    }
}
```

But I am not aware of how to do it in new feature as Hooks, but I am trying to do it this way.

```
const GenerateDescHook = ({ description: initialDesc }) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    setDescription(initialDesc)
  }, {})

 function handleChangeVariance(newVariance) {
    setDescription({
      ...description,
      template: {
        ...description.template,
        variance_name: newVariance,
      },
    })
  }

}
```

Basically, I just need to change description props, which coming from another parent component to turn to state. Pls, could you show me how to do it in new way as Hooks way?

Comment: First concern here was that you're copying props into a local state. Why is that necessary?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pass your initial state as first argument to `useState` like this:

```
const GenerateDescHook = ({ description: initialDesc }) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(initialDesc)

  ...
```

Comment: sorry but it did not help

Comment: @Feruza This is actually the way this should be done, this is hook counterpart to your class component. If it doesn't work for you, you're possibly doing something wrong.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is only fine if the `description` prop passed to the `GenerateDescHook` component never changes and also that the code in the OP has the same drawback. Unless you can guarantee that (which is a dangerous assumption IMO), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55793169/1205753) is probably the better answer.

Comment: @Feruza Why did you accept this answer? If the parent state changes, child state will remain unchanged. The useEffect solution with more votes is what I came here for at least.

Answer (score 82):

The problem in your code is with `{}`.
UseEffect hook expects and array, not an object. Use `[initialDesc]` instead.

**This is how you reset component state when props change**

```
const GenerateDescHook = ({ description: initialDesc }) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setDescription(initialDesc)
  }, [initialDesc]);
}
```

**This is how you initialize component state to prop value on first render only**

```
const GenerateDescHook = ({ description: initialDesc }) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(initialDesc);
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer to handle external change of the property value. without this it will not get synced

Comment: This! I had a component with pageNumber changing externally and `useState(props.initialPageNumber)` would not use the latest value due to some React hidden optimizations. Even though this was two distinct component instances in two separate places of the page. One with `initialPageNumber={1}` and the other with `initialPageNumber={3}`

Answer (score 2):

The initial value of your state is the one passed into `useState` :

```
const GenerateDescHook = ({ description: initialDesc }) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(initialDesc)
```

As the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) states :

```
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is the equivalent of :

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you get the state object? not just an individual prop

Comment: What do you mean by state object ? the variable containing your value is `description`. And hooks don't have any parent variable containing all state values

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to achieve a state which depends on prop value and at the same avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Here is my attempt in creating such a hook:

```js
/**
 * Replacement for useState which depends on prop value and avoids unnecessary re-renders.
 */
export function useStateBasedOnProps(propValue) {
    const [, update] = useState(false);

    const [state, setState] = useMemo(() => {
        const state = {};
        return [
            state,
            (value) => {
                if (value instanceof Function) {
                    state.value = value(state.value);
                } else {
                    state.value = value;
                }
                update((tick) => !tick);
            }
        ];
    }, [update]);

    if (state.prevPropValue !== propValue) {
        state.prevPropValue = propValue;
        state.value = propValue;
    }

    return [state.value, setState];
}
```

Here is a usage example:

```js
function IncButton({initialValue}) {
    const [value, setValue] = useStateBasedOnProps(initialValue);
    const increment = useCallback(() => setValue((prev) => prev + 1), [setValue]);
    return <button onClick={increment}>Click to increment: {value}</button>;
}
```

Full example: https://gist.github.com/mdevils/b861610780300784292194f65886517a