# Should I use useMemo in hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I created useBanner hooks

```
const useBanner = (array, yardage) => {
  const [bannArr, setBannArr] = useState(array.slice(0, yardage));
  const [bannListIndex, setBannIndex] = useState(1);

  return {
   ....
  };
};
```

Am I doing the right thing and the props throw in useState.
It’s permissible to use useBanner.

```
const Banner= ({
  array,
  yardage
}) => {
  const { bannForth, bannBeck, bannArr } = useBanner(array, yardage);
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

when props will change here.
Will change the state in useBanner.
or is it considered anti-patterns I have to write all this in useMemo

```
const useBanner = (array, yardage) => {
  const [bannArr, setBannArr] = useState([]);
  const [bannListIndex, setBannIndex] = useState(1);

 useMemo(() => {
    setBannArr(array.slice(0, yardage));
    setBannIndex(1);
  }, [array, yardage]);


  return {
   ....
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, custom hooks are possible in React. Here is separate document discussing [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

But exactly you sample may require additional code depending on what is your final goal.

1. If you want initialize state only once, when component `Banner` is first created, you can just do as in your first sample

   ```
   const Banner= ({
       array,
       yardage
   }) => {
       const { bannForth, bannBeck, bannArr } = useBanner(array, yardage);
       return (
         ...
       );
   };
   ```

   This will work perfectly. But if props `array` and `yardage` will change, this will not be reflected in component. So `props` will be used only once as initial values and then will not be used in `useBanner` even if changed (And it doesn't matter whether you'll use `useBanner` or `useState` directly). This answer [highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54131100/7141073) this.
2. If you want to update inital values on each `props` change, you can go with `useEffect` like below

   ```
   const Banner= ({
       array,
       yardage
   }) => {
       const { bannForth, bannBeck, bannArr, setBannArr } = useBanner(array, yardage);
       useEffect (() => {
           // setBannArr should also be returned from useBanner. Or bannArr should be changed with any other suitable function returned from useBanner.
           setBannArr(array.slice(0, yardage)); 
       }, [array, yardage, setBannArr])
       return (
         ...
       );
   };
   ```

   In this case `Banner` component can control state itself and when parent component change `props`, state in `Banner` component will be reset to new `props`.

Here is small sample to [showcase second option](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56926343-twpi9).

Comment: Do I understand you correctly..If you create hooks, then the props inside them never changes.my examples are array, yardage they will never change. This means that the initial values can simply be thrown into the State.

Comment: Yes, in `useState` hook initial value applied only once and doesn't change (it doesn't metter whether `useState` is called directly from component or wrapped in `useBanner` function). For other hooks, like `useEffect` `props` will be applied on each re-render and also when they are changed. But if you pass empty array (`[]`) as second argument for `useEffect` it also capture `props` only once.